# Get list of playlists in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am having difficulty in obtaining a collection of playlists for the iPhone with Xamarin.iOS. I want to populate a list of my custom objects with the playlist descriptions. I found a page in Apple documentation on how to do it in Obj-C. However, whatever I do in Xamarin I either get invalid cast exceptions or some other error. 
Getting the playlists into a collection is OK. However, it is getting the name of the playlist after that where the problem lies.

```
    private List<Playlist> GetPlaylists()
    {
        MPMediaQuery mq = MPMediaQuery.playlistsQuery;
        // At this point mq.Collections has a reference to the playlists. However I have no way of getting the Name/Description of the playlist. 
        // Thats why I was attempting to use MPMediaPlaylist
        // MPMediaPlaylist[] mp1 = mq.Collections as MPMediaPlaylist[]; - doesn't work - results in mp1 being null


        List<Playlist> playlists = (from p in mq.Collections
                                    select new Playlist () { PlaylistDescription = ((MPMediaPlaylist)p).ValueForProperty("MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName").ToString()}
                                   ).ToList();
        return playlists;
    }
```

Another variation I had was as follows (but again received an invalid cast exception in the iteration of the forearch i.e. ***MediaPlaylist in mp1***):

```
        MPMediaQuery mq = MPMediaQuery.playlistsQuery;
        Array mp1 = mq.Collections as Array;
        List<Playlist> playlists = new List<Playlist> ();
        foreach (MPMediaPlaylist playlist in mp1) {
            playlists.Add (new Playlist () { PlaylistDescription = playlist.ValueForProperty ("MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName").ToString() });
        }
```

As I have commented i the code, I can get a handle on the playlists through the collections property on the query. However, I cannot get the Name/Title/Description of the playlist. That is why I was attempting to use the **MPMediaPlaylist** casting.

In the immediate window and watch window I tried to cast **(MPMediaPlaylist)mq.collections[0]** but again got an invalid cast exception.

[**I came across the following documentation in apple documentation for Obj-C**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlaylist_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) but I have been unsuccessful in reproducing it as you can see above. I'd be very grateful if someone could cast an eye over what I have above and also this Objective-C link and advise.

Many thanks,

Tomás

Comment: This seems like it should work - it may be a bug.  I'd try submitting a test case to bugzilla.xamarin.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just going to put this here.... if someone runs in to this problem in the future!

So to get list of playlists you should do the following:

```
        MPMediaQuery playlistQuery = MPMediaQuery.PlaylistsQuery;
        MPMediaItemCollection[] playlistCollection = playlistQuery.Collections;

        foreach(MPMediaItemCollection collection in playlistCollection){
            NSString key = MPMediaPlaylistProperty.Name;
            string name = collection.ValueForKey(key).ToString();
            //Do whatever you need with the info 
        }
```